# PSQL - Errors when importing from a "pg_dump"

Tags: sql, postgresql, heroku, psql

I made a pg_dump from one database. By doing

`pg_dump postgres://a/b/c > file.sql`

Then after I import to a different database using.

`psql posgres://x/y/z < file.sql`

I get two repeating errors during the import

Error 1:
`ERROR:  must be owner of extension plpgsql`

Error2: `ERROR:  role username does not exist`

These are two seperate heroku (free) postgres databases so the username, database uri and so on are both completely different.

Are these error messages of any concern?

Note: the export (pg_dump) works fine. Oh and the import looks also that it completely worked.

Note: I'm using Cygwin (with postgres client) and Heroku so the current solutions on SO don't apply (they involve using `sudo`).

**Edit**
Michał Młoźniak suggested

> pg_dump pg_dump --no-acl --no-owner

But this only fixes:

Error2: `ERROR:  role username does not exist`

Answer (score 1):

To fix `ERROR:  must be owner of extension plpgsql`
Try passing additional options to pg_dump `pg_dump --no-acl --no-owner`. Result file will not have any commands for setting ownership, privileges etc.

Comment: If I have already made a dump can I still use this or should i delete it and do it this way. If so why?

Comment: You need to create another dump, because those commands are already in the file. Somethin like `ALTER TABLE table1 OWNER TO something;`. You can also do `pg_dump -Fc` and then import it with `pg_restore --no-owner --no-acl`. The second option still includes ownership commands, but you can ignore them when doing import with `pg_restort`

Comment: I don't use pg restore I used psql posgres://x/y/z < file.sql

Comment: It should say To fix: `ERROR:  role username does not exist` apologies!